# Is it possible in R to create a separate table for all factors against one factor?

Tags: r

I have a CSV file in which there are lots of columns for various factors with which I would want to create a table for each column against a specific one (length). Length can be from 1-10.

E.g.
Factor 1      Factor 2          Length
A               Yes               1
B               Yes               5
C                No               2

In this example, I would have a table showing length's inputs (1-10) on the rows, factor 1's data inputs (A-C) on the columns and in the values set would be the frequency of A, B and C for each length.

I would want to do something similar for factor 2 and all the other 198  factors.

Many thanks

Comment: `table(Length, Factor 1)` or `xtabs(~Length+Factor 1)` after you have imported the .csv file into R. Provide reproducible data for more details.

Comment: please provide a reproducible example ( ie your data and code should be available)